# Safari not show buttons in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, safari

I have a problem only in safari and i cant found a solution. I develop a list of hours and its shows when you select a day, but the problem is in safari, when the user clicks the day, the list of hours didnt show but if you pass the cursor you can click an hour. This is the worst part, when you do a mousedown (select) the list render it. I put some images about this case.

[image: the list dosent show]

[image: mousedown select]

[image: all hours are seen now]

There images are screenshots because rigth now, i dont have a mac :(

This is the code:

```
this.state.showHours &&
    <div className="list-selection__hours">
        <div className="list-selection__hours-list">
            {hours?.map((h: hour, index: number) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} className={"list-selection__hours-list-selecthour" + (h === selectedHour
                        ? " list-selection__hours-list-selecthour-active" : "")} onClick={this.selectHour.bind(this, h)}>
                        {h.show}
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry for my limited english, plasea let me now if anyone have a solution :)

Thx!!